# How to turn fields and values of a model object into keys and values of a dictionary

Tags: python, api, dictionary, model

I am building an app in Django.

I am developing an API service view that returns a list of cities stored in my model, with their features:

```
def cities_list_api(request):
    cities = target_area_input_data.objects.all()
    data = {"cities":list(cities.values("pk","Name","Longitude","Latitude","Radius"))}
    response = JsonResponse(data)
    return response
```

returning:

> {"cities": [{"pk": 2, "Name": "Roma", "Longitude": 12.49,
> "Latitude": 41.89, "Radius": 10.5}, {"pk": 6, "Name": "Ha Noi,
> Vietnam", "Longitude": 105.84, "Latitude": 21.02, "Radius":
> 10.0}, {"pk": 1, "Name": "Milano", "Longitude": 9.19, "Latitude": 45.46, "Radius": 8.0}, {"pk": 3, "Name": "Bologna", "Longitude": 11.34, "Latitude": 44.49, "Radius": 5.5}, {"pk": 4, "Name": "Verona", "Longitude": 10.97,
> "Latitude": 45.41, "Radius": 4.5}, {"pk": 5, "Name": "pszczyna,
> Polonia", "Longitude": 18.93, "Latitude": 49.98, "Radius":
> 3.0}]}

For shorness sake, I can write the same view like:

```
def cities_list_api(request):
    cities = target_area_input_data.objects.all()
    data = {"cities":list(cities.values())}
    response = JsonResponse(data)
    return response
```

So that I con't have to write all the fields inside `values()` parentheses.

Now, I am developing an API service view that returns a city features given the city id.

```
def city_detail_api(request, pk):

    try:
        city = target_area_input_data.objects.get(pk=pk)
        data = {    
                "city":
                    {
                        "pk":city.pk,
                        "Name":city.Name,
                        "Longitude":city.Longitude,
                        "Latitude":city.Latitude,
                        "Radius":city.Radius,

                    }        
                } 
        
        response = JsonResponse(data)
        return response
```

returning:

> {"city": {"pk": 2, "Name": "Roma", "Longitude": 12.494757, "Latitude": 41.892786, "Radius": 10.5}}

I just want all the attibutes of the desired instance displayed in a dictionary, which is saved in the dictionary key `city`, so, for shortness sake, I would like to change that view to this one:

```
def city_detail_api(request, pk):

    try:
        city = target_area_input_data.objects.get(pk=pk)
        data = {
                "city":right_expression     
                } 
        
        response = JsonResponse(data)
        return response
```

What should be the `right_expression`?

How can I avoid to write all the fields even this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use DRF serializers to do that, for example:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name"
            "longitud",
        )
        model = City
```

then in the view:

```
def city_detail_api(request, pk):

    city = target_area_input_data.objects.get(pk=pk)
    data = dict(city=CitySerializer(city).data)
    response = JsonResponse(data)
    return response
```

I think that using DRF is more standart way to do it and it gives you the chance to resolve some calculated fields inside the serializers and also nested another serializers, at the end you will have all power of DRF serializers features.